# Set UImage form local path URL - causes crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimage, ios10

Setting imageviews in collection view with local path URL like this:

```
let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
myImageView.image  =  UIImage(named: fileURL.path)
```

Causes crash - images are high quality - tried to reduce size also - still crashes the app with no error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

let imagePath = (getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("/\(file_name).jpg")

let myImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)!
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in the bundle (included with the app), you don't pass the whole path to `UIImage(named: ...)`, only the filename. So your call would be `UIImage(named: fileName)`

If you have the image in the documents path (you downloaded it from the app) use `UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)`

Comment: contentsOfFile initializer expects a path (not an URL)

Comment: Hi @Dule - Thanks . If i want to show images form gallery - how to do it